# (Tao's Ex.1.1.5) Characterization of Jordan measurability; not able to prove equivalence.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is Ex.1.1.5 from Tao's Introduction to Measure Theory:

> $(\texttt{Characterisation of Jordan measurability})$ Let $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ be bounded. Show that the following are equivalent: $\textbf{(1)}$ E is Jordan measurable.
> $\textbf{(2)}$ For every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exist elementary sets $A \subseteq E \subseteq B$
> such that $m(B \setminus A)  \le  \varepsilon$. $\textbf{(3)}$ For every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists an elementary set $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $m^{*,J}\left(E\Delta C\right) \le \varepsilon$. Where $m_{*,J}(E)$ and $m^{*,J}(E)$ are inner and outer Jordan measures respectively.

**Attempt :** $\textbf{Stuck on the part}, (3) \implies (1).$

$(1)\implies (2) :$ We fix $\varepsilon>0$ and given $A \subseteq E \subseteq B$, where $A,B$ elementary. Now by definition of inner and outer Jordan measure $$m_{*,J}(E) \le m(A)+\tfrac{\varepsilon}{2}~,~m^{*,J}(E) \ge m(B)-\tfrac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$
Now using the fact that $E$ is Jordan measurable we have $$m(B)-\tfrac{\varepsilon}{2}\le m^{*,J}(E)=m_{*,J}(E)\le m(A)+\tfrac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$ Which immediately implies $m(B\setminus A)\le \varepsilon.$

$(2)\implies (3) :$ To this end we choose $C:=B$, then $E\subseteq C$, and notice $E\Delta C=C\setminus E$. Also $C\setminus E \subseteq C\setminus A \implies C \cap E^c \subseteq C\cap A^c$. Now using the fact that if $A,C \in \mathcal{E}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, then $C\setminus E \in \mathcal{E}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ (where $\mathcal{E}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is the set of elementary subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$), and the definition of outer Jordan measure we have : $$m^{*,J}(E\Delta C)=m^{*,J}(C\setminus E)\le m(C\setminus A)=m(B\setminus A) \le \varepsilon.$$

$(3) \implies (1) :$ Given $m(E \Delta C) \le \varepsilon$, we need to show $E$ is Jordan measurable i.e $m^{*,J}(E)=m_{*,J}(E)$. I guess I'll be done if i manage to show $m^{*,J}(E)\le \varepsilon+ m_{*,J}(E)$, for $\varepsilon>0$ arbitrary. I'm not sure how to go ahead from here? Appreciate any suggestions!